# Unique Triangle

Tags: geometry

I was viewing the proof of the converse of the pythagorean theorem, and I noticed that it assumed that $3$ side-lengths create (at max) $1$ distinct triangle. Why is this? Why can't we make multiple unique triangles from $3$ side lengths? Is there some sort of formal proof that can explain this?

Comment: we can make multiple triangles but they all will be congruent

Comment: yes, but why will they be congruent? where is the proof for this?

Comment: Depends on your framework. It's often taken as a postulate, called the SSS congruence postulate.

Comment: this is because side lengths uniquely define angles in the triangle (law of sines, law of cosines)

Comment: But those are taken from the fact that SSS exists. I am asking for why this SSS actually exists.

Comment: You can check the proof by Euclid here https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI8.html